# Gantry and less variables how to bridge the gap?

Tags: joomla, less

Is there a way to update a variables.less file with variables from the user selection area in the backend? such as template-options.xml

or can it only be made inline through a styledeclaration.php?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is to create a php function to update the .less file (fopen etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read http://gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/advanced/less_css.md

You should write a PHP that reads your template-options.xml and create a `/less/[LESS_FILE_NAME]-custom.less` file with your variables, or pass your variables as an array into the `$gantry->addLess()` function.

Comment: I was able to easily do a simple array passing. Thanks for your help. $gantry->addLess('templates/gantry/less/interludic/navbar.less', 'navbar.css', 10, array('passing'=>'#000000'));